# laravel 5.3 how to render html content of a page in a view with a function

Tags: php, laravel, rendering, laravel-5.3

I am facing a rendering problem... in my product.blade.php I would like to show in a part of the page the html content from an external source without iframe. I want to make a call like :

```
{!! View::make('pages.viewer', ['docUrl' => url('get-DocHtml/' . $primaryAttachment->id)]) !!}
```

In my route :

```
Route::get('get-DocHtml/{id}', 'PagesController@getDocHtml');
```

In PagesController.php :

```
public function getDocHtml($id){ 
$attachment = Attachment::find($id);
$filepath = Storage::disk('S3')->url($attachment->filename.'/test.html');
return \Response::make(file_get_contents($filePath), 200, [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8' ]); 
}
```

I don't know how to make it render in viewer.blade.php or directly in my product.blade.php like a all to the function and render it directly...

Is someone has any idea how to render it (without helpers) ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass

```
file_get_contents($filePath)
```

as variable to view?

your method `getDocHtml` should return view in that way:

```
return view('viewer')->with([
    'external' => file_get_contents($filePath)
]);
```

Then you can do anything with passed `$external` variable

Comment: Thanks for your message. I just tried to do it but can't make it works. Can you please give me more information regarding it ? if I do a dd(file_get_contents($filePath)); in my public function getDocHtml, it doesn't give anything in my product.blade.php or view.blade.php shall I keep {!! View::make('pages.viewer', ['docUrl' => url('get-DocHtml/' . $primaryAttachment->id)]) !!} too ?

Comment: if `dd(file_get_contents($filePath))` returns nothing, that means that this file contains nothing. You can return view by `VIew::make` as you did it befre, but additionally add `external` variable (or name it as you want). THen `$external` variable will be present in your view.

Comment: thanks Piotr, it's working ! I had a problem with my controller as my variable was empty.

Comment: Working perfectly with : $file = file_get_contents($filePath); return view('viewer')->withExternal($file);